# With which method are the trends calculated in greenbrown package in R?

Tags: r

I want to use the greenbrown package in R for the calculation of NDVI trends. From its help page, I can see that the main methodology relies on multiple linear regression, but it is not clear to me what is the main method (adapted) behind the trend calculation.

So, I have two related questions :

1. What is the method behind the calculation of trends (AAT method)?
2. Can I use the theil-sen methodology for the calculation of trends with this package?

I appreciate any help / suggestions.

Comment: I think it might be better to email the developer(s). If there is a Github page, perhaps open an issue there?

Comment: @NelsonGon, thank you for your suggestion, I will have an extensive look at Github!